# After upgrade to xubuntu 12.10 I have 2 mount points for each partition

Tags: 12.10, thunar, pcmanfm, mountpoint

Just upgraded Xubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 (both XFCE and LXDE desktops are being used at this system). Now I have 2 mount points for each partition. It looks like this:

[image: mount points doubled]

It appears this way in both Thunar and PCManFM. However, there are no dupes in Nautilus.

```bash
$ ls /dev/disk/by-id/
ata-ST320410A_5FB3MA76         ata-ST3250620A_9RT030B0-part3  scsi-SATA_ST320410A_5FB3MA76-part1   scsi-SATA_ST3250620A_9RT030B0-part4
ata-ST320410A_5FB3MA76-part1   ata-ST3250620A_9RT030B0-part4  scsi-SATA_ST320410A_5FB3MA76-part2   scsi-SATA_ST3250620A_9RT030B0-part5
ata-ST320410A_5FB3MA76-part2   ata-ST3250620A_9RT030B0-part5  scsi-SATA_ST320410A_5FB3MA76-part3   scsi-SATA_ST3250620A_9RT030B0-part6
ata-ST320410A_5FB3MA76-part3   ata-ST3250620A_9RT030B0-part6  scsi-SATA_ST3250620A_9RT030B0        scsi-SATA_ST3250620A_9RT030B0-part7
ata-ST3250620A_9RT030B0        ata-ST3250620A_9RT030B0-part7  scsi-SATA_ST3250620A_9RT030B0-part1  scsi-SATA_ST3250620A_9RT030B0-part8
ata-ST3250620A_9RT030B0-part1  ata-ST3250620A_9RT030B0-part8  scsi-SATA_ST3250620A_9RT030B0-part2
ata-ST3250620A_9RT030B0-part2  scsi-SATA_ST320410A_5FB3MA76   scsi-SATA_ST3250620A_9RT030B0-part3

$ ls /dev/disk/by-uuid/
01CD9E239FDF54F0                      5299-430B                             8824C9E324C9D3FA                      b05c582e-77df-4b83-8a75-17db1ab5dbc1
09a9cf9e-6af4-45ed-a9ac-782c764fe8d1  6bbd501e-7601-4ee7-b725-d3ec7f19f149  8B7C-BAF8                             f54ee301-4bd4-40e3-a9fb-75ca79c05974
50366CC66E8BA293                      8553dc4a-5d63-4078-9be3-ea91a46d8c67  a5be1bcd-b7c6-4273-8ade-eb9cce15504d
```

There are no SCSI drives in this system. What could cause this problem? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me as well.  I was just experimenting with settings when I found a way to remove the duplicates.  It is by no means a solution, but I thought I'd share the observation.

There is a setting in Settings Editor called "/desktop-icons/style" and if you change it from the default 2 to 1 and then back to 2, the duplicates are gone...  You can alternatively run the following two lines:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /desktop-icons/style -s 1
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /desktop-icons/style -s 2
```

I'm not really sure of the reason, this was just something I observed.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for a solution for this same issue... Have not found anything yet.

I did open a question, and a bug on this issue:

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/215089

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1082726

It would be good if folks could confirm the existence of this bug on launchpad, so it'll get some attention!

EDIT: It appears this was already documented as a bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfdesktop4/+bug/1072137

An updated version of xfdesktop4 is available on the Quantal proposed repository that fixes the issue.